# Edittext in the Fragment jumps to the top while editing and overlaps a toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I just try to add an Edittext in the fragment, but while editing the keyboard push up all views in the fragment to the top that overlaps Toolbar and TabLayout.

I tried with Frame Layout / Relative and Constraint Layout for fragment. Same result..

Parent`s Layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UserData.PolicyActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One"
            android:id="@+id/privacy_policy"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Two"
            android:id="@+id/terms_conditions"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/contact_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Three" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/profileVPPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="610dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Fragment

```
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ContactUsFragment">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactUsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Text View"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactUsTitle" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTopics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_for_spinner"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerContactTopic"
        android:textAlignment="center"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="55dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactUsMesBody"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:maxLength="150"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerTopics" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Add the second line in your activity tag in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Solvered by this
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"